# Differential Equation + Integration

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

For ii) Did I do something wrong here? I can't arrive at the correct answer when I sub in N=40.

My working:
[image]

Comment: I think you factored $100N-N^2$ as $(10+N)(10-N)$? It should be $N(100-N)$.

Comment: Oh my gawwd. I kept staring at my working for hours and I din't realize this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the information given we can say that:
$$\frac{dN}{dt}\propto N\times(1-0.01N)$$
since it is proportional we know it will be multiplied by a constant, so:
$$\frac{dN}{dt}=kN(1-0.01N)$$
now we want to do separation of variables, which gives us:
$$\int\frac{1}{N(1-0.01N)}dN=\int kdt$$
$$kt+C=\int\frac 1NdN-\int\frac{0.01}{0.01N-1}dN$$
$$kt+C_1=\ln|N|-\ln|0.01N-1|$$
Which we can rearrange and redefine our integration constant to give:
$$t=\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(\frac{N}{0.01N-1}\right)+C_2$$
we are also given that when $t=0,N=20,N'=0.32$ we can therefore apply this to our equations:
$$\frac{dN}{dt}:\,\,0.32=k\times20(1-0.01\times20)\Rightarrow\,\,16k=0.32\Rightarrow\,\,k=0.02$$
$$N:\,\,0=\frac{1}{0.02}\ln\left(\frac{20}{-0.8}\right)+C_2\Rightarrow C_2=-\frac{1}{0.02}\ln\left(\frac{20}{-0.8}\right)$$
Now you can apply this to the formula to get the complete equation

Comment: ..Domo Arigato!